# Random.choice() photo python-telegram-bot issue

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I need the bot send a photo randomly when the user send a message with word "word". But with the code i wrote, send only one photo and not randomly, like a list of words. I don't know how it is possible to do.
This is the code:

```
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters,
                          ConversationHandler, BaseFilter)
    import random
    updater = Updater(token="")
    bot=telegram.Bot(token="")
    dispatcher=updater.dispatcher
    photo_list=["/path/path/photo_1.jpg", "/path/path/photo_2.jpg","/path/path/photo_3.jpg")]
    prove=random.choice(photo_list)

    class Filter_photo(BaseFilter):
        def filter(self, message):
            return 'word' in message.text
    filter_a = Filter_photo()
    def word(bot, update):
            bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo=open(prove, "rb")
    a_handler = MessageHandler(filter_a, word)
    dispatcher.add_handler(a_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: You set `prove` exactly one time, during the initial running of this code - did you really think that `random.choice()` would somehow create a variable that magically takes on a different value each time you access it?  You need to make the choice inside `word()`, so a new choice is made each time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not really figure out where the problem was, because if i try with a list of words with `random.choice()` the output is a random words and not only one like pictures.